# Inequality involving Pochhammer symbols

Tags: inequality, special-functions

Let $m,S$ be integers satisfying $2\leq m\leq S$. I would like to show that

$$h_1\left(x\right) h_3\left(x\right) \leq h_2^2\left(x\right)$$

for all $x\geq 0$ where

$$h_k\left(x\right) \equiv {}_2F_1\left(k,k-1-m;S-m+k,-x\right).$$

${}_2F_1$ denotes the hypergeometric function.

> **What I have so far...**
>
> Note that \begin{multline*}
> h_{1}\left(y\right)h_{3}\left(y\right)=\sum_{d=0}^{\infty}\left(-y\right)^{d}\sum_{p=0}^{d}\frac{\left(1\right)^{\left(p\right)}\left(-m\right)^{\left(p\right)}}{\left(S-m+1\right)^{\left(p\right)}p!}\frac{\left(3\right)^{\left(q\right)}\left(2-m\right)^{\left(q\right)}}{\left(S-m+3\right)^{\left(q\right)}q!}\\
> =\sum_{d=0}^{\infty}y^{d}\sum_{p=0}^{d}\frac{m_{p}}{\left(S-m+1\right)^{\left(p\right)}}\frac{\left(q+1\right)\left(q+2\right)\left(m-2\right)_{q}}{2\left(S-m+3\right)^{\left(q\right)}}
> \end{multline*} where $q\equiv d-p$ and the Pochhammer symbols are
>   defined here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol.
>   Similarly, \begin{multline*}
> h_{2}^{2}\left(y\right)=\sum_{d=0}^{\infty}\left(-y\right)^{d}\sum_{p=0}^{d}\frac{\left(2\right)^{\left(p\right)}\left(1-m\right)^{\left(p\right)}}{\left(S-m+2\right)^{\left(p\right)}p!}\frac{\left(2\right)^{\left(q\right)}\left(1-m\right)^{\left(q\right)}}{\left(S-m+2\right)^{\left(q\right)}q!}\\
> =\sum_{d=0}^{\infty}y^{d}\sum_{p=0}^{d}\frac{\left(p+1\right)\left(m-1\right)_{p}}{\left(S-m+2\right)^{\left(p\right)}}\frac{\left(q+1\right)\left(m-1\right)_{q}}{\left(S-m+2\right)^{\left(q\right)}}.
> \end{multline*}
>   So it is sufficient to show $$
> \sum_{p=0}^{d}\frac{\left(q+1\right)\left(q+2\right)m_{p}\left(m-2\right)_{q}}{2\left(S-m+1\right)^{\left(p\right)}\left(S-m+3\right)^{\left(q\right)}}-\frac{\left(q+1\right)\left(p+1\right)\left(m-1\right)_{p}\left(m-1\right)_{q}}{\left(S-m+2\right)^{\left(p\right)}\left(S-m+2\right)^{\left(q\right)}}\leq0, $$ for all $d\geq0$.
>
> Note that for $d \geq 2m - 1$, the above is zero (see also
>   @Semiclassical's comment below), so that we only have to verify the
>   claim for $0 \leq d \leq 2\left(m -1\right)$.

Comment: Note that $k-1\leq 2\leq m$. Therefore the second parameter of your hypergeometrics are always negative integers. But then $(-N)^{(N+1)}=0$ and so the series always terminates---your hypergeometric functions are polynomials in $z$. Looking at a page on the [DLMF website](http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.9), I think they might be related to Jacobi polynomials (not sure).

Comment: @par, $(q+1)*(q+2)$ and $(p+1)*(q+1)$ look suspicious is there a hidden typo?

Comment: @andre: I'm afraid it is not a typo

Comment: @par, the first time $q$ and $q$ the second time $p$ and $q$?

Comment: @par, I was also irritated about your and wikipedia's usage of Pochhammer symbols, which is different from http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/toc.htm and the one in the DLMF link above.

Comment: @par, and how did you move the sign of $-x$ into your falling pochhammer symbols e.g. $m_p (m-2)_q$?

Comment: @andre: I have rewritten the question and have shown all of my work to get to the polynomial inequality. The negative signs are removed since $(-k)^\left(n\right)=\left(-1\right)^n k_n$ whenever $k\geq 0$.

Comment: I am quite sure that your inequality follows from http://www.jstor.org/stable/20535536

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, I supoose this article deals with the same hypergeometric functions as in the same author's dissertation, https://dea.lib.unideb.hu/dea/bitstream/handle/2437/109019/ertekezes.pdf (PDF p.32). $h_k(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $(m-k+1)$. Whereas the $P_n(x)$ in the articles are the ordinary Jacobi polynomials of degree $n$. The Turan type inequality  poses some restriction on $x$, which the OP doesn't. And it is not clear to me, how to map the $h_k$ onto the $P_n$, which has a hypergeometric parameter independent of $n$.

Comment: @par, at least I want to mention the easiest case, one should prove $h_k(x) = (1+x)^{m-k+1}$ for $2 \le k \le m = S$. Which implies $h_{k-1}(x)h_{k+1}(x) = h_k^2(x)$.

Comment: Probably not related, but your proposed inequality made me think about [Newton's inequalities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_inequalities).

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas, also similar terms regarding $h_{k-1}(x)h_{k+1}(x) = h_k^2(x)$, appear in Halley's Method, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder%27s_method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Added 2014-09-01:*

- Some mistakes corrected in the calculation of the coefficients of $h_2^2(x)-h_1(x)h_3(x)$
- Two interesting references regading *log-concavity* added

---

*Note:* This is not a complete answer but hopefully a proper approach towards a solution. As I started from scratch it looks somewhat different compared to the calculations from @par. At the time I can provide two additional aspects.

> 1.) *A nice representation of  $h_k$:*

Let $h_k={}_{2}F_{1}(k,k-1-m;S-m+k;-x)$  with  $2\leq m\leq S$  and $k\in\{1,2,3\}$. The following is valid:

> \begin{align*}
> h_k=\frac{1}{\binom{S}{m-k+1}}\sum_{n=k}^{m}\binom{n}{k-1}\binom{S}{m-n}x^{n-k+1}
> \end{align*}

This follows from

\begin{align*}
h_k&={}_{2}F_{1}(k,k-1-m;S-m+k;-x)\\
&=\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{(k)_n(k-1-m)_n}{(S-m+k)_n}\frac{(-x)^n}{n!}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{m-k+1}\frac{(k)_n(m-k+2-n)_n}{(S-m+k)_n}\frac{x^n}{n!}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{m-k+1}\frac{(n+k-1)!}{(k-1)!}\frac{(m-k+1)!}{(m-n-k+1)!}\frac{(S-m+k-1)!}{(S-m+n+k-1)!}\frac{x^n}{n!}\\
&=\frac{1}{\binom{S}{m-k+1}}\sum_{n=1}^{m-k+1}\binom{n+k-1}{n}\binom{S}{m-n-k+1}x^n\\
&=\frac{1}{\binom{S}{m-k+1}}\sum_{n=k}^{m}\binom{n}{k-1}\binom{S}{m-n}x^{n-k+1}
\end{align*}

So, for $k\in\{1,2,3\}$ we get a representation for $h_k$ which looks attractive:

> \begin{align*}
> h_1(x)&=\frac{1}{\binom{S}{m}}\sum_{n=1}^{m}\binom{S}{m-n}x^n\\
> h_2(x)&=\frac{1}{\binom{S}{m-1}}\sum_{n=2}^{m}n\binom{S}{m-n}x^{n-1}\tag{1}\\
> h_3(x)&=\frac{1}{2\binom{S}{m-2}}\sum_{n=3}^{m}n(n-1)\binom{S}{m-n}x^{n-2}
> \end{align*}

We clearly see, that essentially differentiating $h_1$ generates $h_2$ and $h_3$. But at the time I couldn't find a way to use this fact in order to show the *log-concavity property* of $h_k$:

> \begin{align*}
> h_2^{2}(x) \geq h_1(x)h_3(x) \qquad\qquad x>0\tag{2}
> \end{align*}

While playing with the $h_k$ and doing some computation another interesting aspect appeared:

> 2.) **Crucial assumption:** The polynomial $h_2^2(x)-h_1(x)h_3(x)$ has *non-negative coefficients* only.
>
> If we can show that the coefficients $$[x^n](h_2^2(x)-h_1(x)h_3(x))\geq 0$$ for all $n\geq 0$ the *log-concavity property* (2) follows immediately.

Using following shortcuts in (1): 
$$\beta_m=\binom{S}{m}^{-1}\quad\text{and}\quad a_n=\binom{S}{m-n}$$
we can write

> \begin{align*}
> h_1(x)&=\beta_m\sum_{n=1}^{m}a_nx^n\\
> h_2(x)&=\beta_{m-1}\sum_{n=2}^{m}na_nx^{n-1}\\
> h_3(x)&=\frac{1}{2}\beta_{m-2}\sum_{n=3}^{m}n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}
> \end{align*}

In fact $a_n$ also depends on $m$ but this won't matter in the following calculation and I'd like to keep the notation simple.

Now we first calculate $h_1(x)h_3(x)$ and $h_2^2(x)$.

> \begin{align*}
> h_1(x)&h_3(x)=\\
> &=\frac{1}{2x^2}\beta_m\beta_{m-2}\sum_{j=1}^{m}a_jx^j\sum_{l=3}^{m}l(l-1)a_lx^l\\
> &=\frac{1}{2x^2}\beta_m\beta_{m-2}\sum_{n=4}^{2m}\sum_{{j+l=n}\atop{{1\leq j \leq m}\atop{3\leq l \leq m}}}l(l-1)a_ja_lx^n\\
> &=\frac{1}{2}\beta_m\beta_{m-2}\left(\sum_{n=4}^{m+1}\sum_{j=1}^{n-3}(n-j)(n-j-1)a_ja_{n-j}x^{n-2}\right.\\
> &\qquad+\sum_{n=m+2}^{m+2}\sum_{j=n-m}^{m-1}(n-j)(n-j-1)a_ja_{n-j}x^{n-2}\\
> &\qquad+\left.\sum_{n=m+3}^{2m}\sum_{j=n-m}^{m}(n-j)(n-j-1)a_ja_{n-j}x^{n-2}\right)\tag{3}\\
> \end{align*}

and

> \begin{align*}
> h_2^2(x)&=\frac{1}{x^2}\beta_{m-1}^{2}\sum_{j=2}^{m}ja_jx^j\sum_{l=2}^{m}la_lx^l\\
> &=\frac{1}{x^2}\beta_{m-1}^{2}\sum_{n=4}^{2m}\sum_{{j+l=n}\atop{2\leq j,l \leq m}}jla_ja_lx^n\\
> &=\beta_{m-1}^{2}\left(\sum_{n=4}^{m+2}\sum_{j=2}^{n-2}j(n-j)a_ja_{n-j}x^{n-2}\right.\\
> &\qquad+\left.\sum_{n=m+3}^{2m}\sum_{j=n-m}^{m}j(n-j)a_ja_{n-j}x^{n-2}\right)\tag{4}\\
> \end{align*}

Observe, that the inner sums in (3) and (4) have different index ranges which is the reason for splitting the outer sum. We have to respect this when calculating the coefficients. Therefore we split the calculation of the coefficients for $[x^n](h_2^2(x)-h_1(x)h_3(x))$ into 3 parts accordingly to
\begin{align*}
4 \leq& n \leq m+1\\
&n=m+2\\
m+3 \leq &n \leq 2m
\end{align*}

Here's the calculation for the first index region $4 \leq n \leq m+1$. The other calculations can be done analogously.

> The coefficients of the polynomial $h_2^2(x)-h_1(x)h_3(x)$ with $n\in \{4,\dots,m+1\}$ are
>
> \begin{align*}
> [x^{n-2}]&(h_2^2(x)-h_1(x)h_3(x))=\\
> &=2(n-2)\beta_{m-1}^2a_2a_{n-2}\tag{5}\\
> &\quad+\sum_{j=2}^{n-3}(n-j)a_ja_{n-j}\left(\beta^2_{m-1}j-\frac{1}{2}\beta_m\beta_{m-2}(n-j-1)\right)\tag{6}\\
> &\quad-\frac{1}{2}\beta_m\beta_{m-2}(n-1)(n-2)a_1a_{n-1}\tag{7}
> \end{align*}

So, the idea is to find a proper estimate in order to show that the coefficients above are *non-negative*.

> *Computational plausbility checks:*

Computation of some values of $S$ and $2\leq m \leq S$ supports the assumption and the calculations show that the middle sum (6) is non-negative whenever $m\neq S$. In case $m = S$, the difference of the first summand (5) and the third summand (7) is always greater than the middle sum (6), so that the coefficients are always non-negative.

> *Log-concavity:*

*Note:* The log-concavity seems to be ubiquitiuos within this example. For every $n$ the sequence of binomial coefficients $\{\binom{n}{k}\}$ is *log-concave*, so that e.g.

$$\binom{S}{m-1}^2\geq\binom{S}{m-2}\binom{S}{m}$$

holds, which could be helpful for estimating the coefficients when trying to simplify (2) and (4), resp. (3).

> *Interesting papers regarding log-concavity:*

Recently I found two interesting papers from *Dmitry Karp*, *Sergei Sitnik* and *Segrei Kalmykov*. I think, they both provide valuable information for the current problem. One is a [Survey about *log-convexity* and *log-concavity*](http://math.nist.gov/~DLozier/SF21/SF21slides/Karp.pdf) discussing also hypergeometric functions. The other one deals with [Log-convexity and log-concavity of hypergeometric-like functions](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0902.3073v1.pdf). In the second paper the section containing *Theorem 6* looks promising.

Comment: Mark (I'm working with Par on this at UW), thanks so much for your help. We will play around with this! Will get back to you.

Comment: Also its sweet to know that the property we are trying to show actually has a name, which means the property we are trying to show within the context of another system is, possibly, more widely applicable.

Comment: @Tommy: Good to see, the information is useful :-) This evening I'll try to make some further progress. Best regards,

Comment: @Markus, I would like to add, that you are using the more widely used definition of the Pochhammer symbols, which differ from the ones given in the OP.

Comment: @Andre: Yes, you're right. I should have mentioned it. The notation I use is heavily used in many classics. So, e.g Donald E. Knuth uses it and I admire besides many other things his thoughtful usage of notation. You can find it also in the classic [Generalized Hypergeometric Functions](http://www.amazon.de/gp/product/052109061X) from Lucy Joan Slater.

Comment: @par: I found some mistakes in my calculations which I have corrected now. Maybe you find the papers from *Dmitry Karp* interesting. I think, he's really an expert when dealing with log-concavity questions and he's also a member of Math Overflow!!! Maybe you'd also like to ask him for providing some hints! :-)

Comment: @MarkusScheuer: Sorry for the late reply! Reading his work now.

Comment: @MarkusScheuer Theorem 8.d would be *exactly* what we want if the condition had $b \leq c$ (instead of $b \geq c$) and it said "concave" taking $a=0,b=-1-m,c=S-m$

Comment: The material written by Dmitry that you referred me to as looks promising. I think this will most likely yield results.

Comment: @Tommy: Yes, Theo 8.d is a promising candidate. Also the last condition with the transformation $x\rightarrow -\frac{1}{x}$ could be interesting. In any case it's worthwile to study the proof of Theo 8.d. Best regards,

Comment: @par: Thank you for accepting my answer and granting the bounty. In the next time I'll also check in some detail the papers from Dmitry Karp. In case you find a complete solution, it would be fine to also post it as an answer. Best regards,

Comment: @MarkusScheuer: Hi Markus. An update: we proved a similar result earlier this year (though not the one asked above). It is in Section 5 of http://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.00291.pdf. You and Dmitrii Karp are mentioned in the acknowledgements.

Comment: @par: Dear par! Congratulation to your nice publication! It's a great pleasure and honor to find my name mentioned in your paper! :-) Many thanks for it and all the best to you for your further projects and publications.

Answer (score 2):

I'll prove here some other easy cases, the first being in the comments.

My numerical experiments indicate that one should require $2 \le k \le m \le S$ to show
\begin{align}
q_k(x) := h_{k-1}(x)h_{k+1}(x) - h_{k}^2(x) \le 0
\end{align}
Step 0, one sees immediately that $h_k(x) = h_{k,S,m}(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $(m-k+1)$.

Step 1, $m=k$, one has
\begin{align}
h_{k-1,S,k}(x) &= 1+\frac{(2k-2)}{(S-1)}x+\frac{k(k-1)}{S(S-1)}x^2\\
h_{k,S,k}(x) &= 1+\frac{k}{S}x\\
h_{k+1,S,k}(x) &= 1
\end{align}
which gives
\begin{align}
q_k(x)
&= h_{k-1,S,k}(x)\:h_{k+1,S,k}(x)-h_{k,S,k}(x)^2\\
&= \left(1+\frac{(2k-2)}{(S-1)}x+\frac{k(k-1)}{S(S-1)}x^2\right)\cdot 1 -\left(1+\frac{k}{S}x\right)^2\\
&= -x(2S+kx)\frac{(S-k)}{(S-1)S^2}.
\end{align}

This is clearly a degree 2 polynomial in x with zeros $\{-2S/k,0\}$.
So $x\ge0$ gives $q_k(x) \le 0$. $\square$

Step 2, $m=k+1$, $2 \le k \le k+1 \le S$, we have
\begin{equation}
(5kS+3S-k-3)\ge (5k(k+1)+3(k+1)-k-3) = 5k^2+7k+6 > 0,
\end{equation}
which gives
\begin{align}
q_k(x) = -x(2S(S^2-1)+S(5kS+3S-k-3)x
+4k(k+1)Sx^2+k(k+1)^2x^3)\frac{(S-k-1)}{(S-2) (S-1)^2 S^2} \le 0. \square
\end{align}

Now the easy coefficients of the general case. Step 0, gives that $\text{deg}(q_k(x)) = 2m-2k+2$.

Step 3, $r\ge 2$, $m=k+r$, $2\le k\le k+r \le S$, one has, without proving the equality,
\begin{align}
[x^0](q_k(x)) &= 0,\\
[x^1](q_k(x)) &= -2\cdot\frac{(S+1)(S-k-r)}{(S-r-1)(S-r+0)(S-r+1)} \le 0,\\
[x^{2r+1}](q_k(x)) &= -(2r+2)\cdot\frac{
(S-k-r)
\prod\limits_{\nu=0}^{r-1}(k+\nu)
\prod\limits_{\nu=1}^{r}(k+\nu)
}{
\prod\limits_{\nu=0}^{r}(S-\nu)
\prod\limits_{\nu=1}^{r+1}(S-\nu)
} \le 0,\\
[x^{2r+2}](q_k(x)) &= -\frac{
(S-k-r)
\prod\limits_{\nu=0}^{r}(k+\nu)
\prod\limits_{\nu=1}^{r}(k+\nu)
}{
\prod\limits_{\nu=0}^{r}(S-\nu)
\prod\limits_{\nu=0}^{r+1}(S-\nu)
} \le 0.\square
\end{align}

Next the remaining three cases for $r=2$.

Step 4, $r=2$, $m=k+r$, $2\le k\le k+r \le S$, we have

\begin{align}
(3kS+2S-4k-4) & \ge (3k(k+2)+2(k+2)-4k-4) \ge 3k^2+4k > 0,\\
(4kS+2S+k-4) & \ge (4k(k+2)+2(k+2)+k-4) \ge 4k^2+11k > 0, \\
(7kS+11S-2k-7) & \ge (7k(k+2)+11(k+2)-2k-7) \ge 7k^2+23k+15 > 0,
\end{align}

which gives, without proving the equality,
\begin{align}
[x^2](q_k(x)) &= -3(3kS+2S-4k-4)\cdot\frac{(S-k-2)(S+1)}{(S-3)(S-2)^2(S-1)S} \le 0,\\
[x^3](q_k(x)) &= -4(4kS+2S+k-4)\cdot\frac{(S-k-2)(k+1)}{(S-3)(S-2)^2(S-1)S}
\le 0,\\
[x^4](q_k(x)) &= -2(7kS+11S-2k-7)\cdot\frac{(S-k-2)k(k+1)}{(S-3)(S-2)^2(S-1)^2S} \le 0. \square
\end{align}

Comment: In fact, with respect to the above, in our numerical simulations, sometimes $k$ has to be *increased* for the inequality to hold for a given $S,m$ pair.

Comment: This came from a finite population queuing system. $S$ is the size of the population, and $m$ is the number of resources serving the population. Usually $m << S$ due to multiplexing. $K$ is a not-so-intuitive sizing parameter that is out of context here, but it sort of represents how aggressive you want the sizing to be, e.g., a smaller $k$ leads to a larger $m$ (more resources per person) and a larger $k$ leads to a smaller $m$. The identity trying to be proven came from  trying to prove that a system of equations being iterated to solve for the system parameters always converges.

Comment: That is, $h_1h_3/h_2^2$ is the derivative of the function being iterated, so if this derivative is less than 1, the iterates get smaller and smaller and convergence is guaranteed, hence trying to show the inequality $h_1h_3 < h_2^2$. I am really confident that $k$ should not be bounded above however, because increasing $k$ numerically always leads to convergence.

Comment: @Tommy, would you mind telling us the function, where $h_1h_3/h_2^2$ is the derivative from?

Comment: @andre: I think there was a misunderstanding. $k\geq 2$ is fine, since we are only interested in the case $k=2$. Looking back on the notation I decided, it was not the best choice; the sums are all terminating for the cases that we are interested in.

Comment: @andre: the original function is $h_2/h_1^2$. We wanted to show this was monotonically decreasing. Differentiate this and you get $\left(\xi_2 h_1h_3-2\xi_1 h_2\right)/h_1^3$ where $\xi_2 \leq 2\xi_1$. Therefore, showing $h_1h_3-h_2\leq 0$ is sufficient ($h_k^\prime = \xi_k h_{k+1}$ where $\xi_k = k\left(m+1-k\right)/\left(S-m+k\right)$).

Comment: Uh, yes, sorry. We had a parameter $K$ in our original problem, but it was not necessary to introduce that parameter here. I mistaked the clash of notation as referring to that parameter, but I do not care what happens w.r.t. $k$ here. Sorry!

Comment: @andre: $h_1 = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{m_n}{(S-m+1)^{(n)}} x^n$ (using the "bad" Pochhammer notation) which is nonnegative for $x\geq 0$. It is strictly positive since for $n=0$, the summand becomes $1>0$.

Comment: The same argument can be used for all integer $k$ with $0 \leq k\leq m+1$.